# Creating XML nodes using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am having problems creating nodes and adding them to an XML file:

```
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
</mainnode>
```

I want to be able to add to the file like so:

```
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
</mainnode>
```

I am having trouble getting the concept of adding nodes with Nokogiri.

This is my current code:

```
def openXML
    f = File.open("file.xml")
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
end

def parseXML
    mainnode.name = 'mainnode'
    f = openXML
    temp = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "secnode", f
    mainnode.add_next_sibling(temp)

end
```

What concepts am I missing?

I need to be able to add instance variables to `<data1>` and `<data2>` but I found the Nokogiri tutorial to not be of much help in this area and have not made it past just adding the `<secnode>` node as a child of `<mainnode>`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting from the above code?

Comment: also: what is `inst` ?

Comment: im getting an error inst is undefined. but my problem lies in that i don't know how to initialize inst as the parent node <mainnode> to append the child node <secnode>.

Comment: you haven't defined an `inst` yet...  ie there is no line of code that says `inst =  <something>`

Comment: ohh sorry i changed the name for clarity from my actual code. editing now

Comment: so: the code you want is something like: `inst = temp.<get _node('mainnode')>` (where I don't know what the `get_node` function is called, but there must be one) right?

Comment: right that makes a bit more sense... so now there's no `mainnode = <something>` and it should be that line that is where you fetch the `<mainnode>` section from the xml? So something like `mainnode = f.<get_node('mainnode')>` ?

Comment: have you tried xpath? eg `mainnode = f.xpath('//mainnode/')` or similar? (note: not tested)

Comment: the .add_next_sibling method is not a method of xpath class

Comment: xpath returns an array. cannot append a node to it.

Comment: so, grab the first element out of that array?

Comment: well in this case there would only be one element if i did an .xpath for <mainnode>. there is only one mainnode. but how then would i update my xml file to include additional <secnode>. if all i have is an array how then do i update my file? i could see parsing the file to string and then making a new file with the added <secnode> being done through string manipulation instead of appending nodes. But i feel like this is a step that is not best practice...

Comment: if you can add a sibling... can you append a child? Once you have the mainnode - you append your secnode to it as a child node? I don't know what you intend to do with the final structure once you're don with it...

Comment: What you want to do isn't clear. Do you want to duplicate an existing node and its children? Do you want to add an additional node that is *similar* to the previous and just didn't change the tags or text making it apparent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding nodes in Nokogiri is a lot easier than you think it is, but your question isn't very clear.

If you want to *duplicate* an existing node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
</mainnode>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

secnode = doc.at('secnode')
doc.root.add_child secnode.dup
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which, when run, results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1/>
         <data2/>
    </secnode>
<secnode>
         <data1/>
         <data2/>
    </secnode></mainnode>
```

The funky alignment is the result of appending the intervening text nodes used for indentation. The resulting XML is valid.

If you're adding a different set of nodes, it's still easy:

require 'nokogiri'

```
xml = <<EOT
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
</mainnode>
EOT

node_to_add = <<EOT
<secnode>
  <data3 />
  <data4 />
</secnode>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.root.add_child node_to_add
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1/>
         <data2/>
    </secnode>
<secnode>
  <data3/>
  <data4/>
</secnode>
</mainnode>
```

You can use that as a template:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1></data2>
         <data2></data2>
    </secnode>
</mainnode>
EOT

v1 = 'foo'
v2 = 'bar'
node_to_add = <<EOT
<secnode>
  <data3>#{ v1 }</data3>
  <data4>#{ v2 }</data4>
</secnode>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

doc.root.add_child node_to_add
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mainnode>
    <secnode>
         <data1/>
         <data2/>
    </secnode>
<secnode>
  <data3>foo</data3>
  <data4>bar</data4>
</secnode>
</mainnode>
```

Nokogiri makes it very easy to create nodes to be added by using string representations of the XML or HTML, which it then converts on the fly.

Comment: yea, way better than my 12 line implementation. Thank you for the insights!

Comment: In the Nokogiri docs, you'll see `node_or_tags` as a parameter for various methods. That's how they describe using a string or text representation like I did.

Comment: So it's either or. I can append node to node, or string(tags) to node.

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what other thing you'd want to do. If you have a bunch of nodes already parsed, perhaps as a fragment, you can either do string manipulation via `to_html` or `to_xml` then play with it, or use them as is.

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'nokogiri'

def parse_xml_file(file_name)
  f = File.read(file_name)
  Nokogiri::XML(f) # do not need variable here; it's the return value of the method
end

def add_element(doc, node_name)
  new_element = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new(node_name, doc)
  new_element.content = "anything"
  doc.root.add_child(new_element)
end

doc = parse_xml_file("sample.xml")
add_element(doc, 'secnode')

puts doc.to_s
```

Your line `mainnode.name = 'mainnode'` isn't doing anything and will throw an error; you haven't selected anything from the XML document yet.

You should read up on traversing an XML DOM and selecting nodes. Try this primer:
https://blog.engineyard.com/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri

You say you read the Nokogiri docs, but I'd go back and re-read this, too:
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Finally, play around with nokogiri by parsing a doc in IRB and seeing what you can do with it. That's a good way to explore and get a feel for nokogiri.

Comment: at first i was getting an issue. the only addition to the page after your code was </secnode>. My issue was i did not add any content to the node. after content was added with new_element.content it worked. good suggestions, i spent a couple hours in irb and more docs. Thank you.